# template class with static data member used across DLL/SO

Tags: c++, templates, static, export

Suppose I have such a template class:

```
template <class T>
class Queue
{
public:
    static int Size;
};

template <class T> int Queue<T>::Size = 0;
```

And I export a function in D.dll use Queue as an parameter:

```
void ChangeQueueSize(Queue<int>& q)
{
    q.Size = 100;
}
```

And then I use this exported function in an A.exe:

```
Queue<int> q;

q.Size = 10; 

ChangeQueueSize(q);

int updatedSize = q.Size;
```

Since the Queue class is generated from the class template in 2 projects, there are actually 2 copies of the code, as well as the static data member.

So calling ChangeQueueSize won't really change queue size here, it just update another class's static member, which happens to be have the same class name.

What can we do to solve this problem?
**Is weak symbol in gcc capable of address this?**
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot put templates in a library in the way you might think. You can only put actual, instantiated class definitions in a library.

Templates are essentially a code generation tool, and you can only put generated code into the library.

You might want to use explicit template instantiation to make the compiler generate the code, and take the static member definition *out of* the header:

```
// Header, shipped to clients
template <class T>
class Queue
{
public:
    static int Size;
};

// Library source code:
template <typename T> int Queue<T>::size = 0;

template class Queue<int>;
```

Now compile the source file into the library; this will contain the instance of the static member variable `Queue<int>::size`.

Note that your consumers will only be able to use instances of your class with `T = int` since they don't have access to the static member otherwise (i.e. they'd have to provide their own).

Comment: thanks, I can use declspec(dllexport)/declspec(dllimport) along with your way to "export" Queue<int> thus dll and client share the code. Do you have any idea on how to implement this in Linux, seems it don't have such mechanism.

Comment: You don't need `declspec` on Linux. Just make it a platform-conditional macro that does nothing on Linux.

Comment: I didn't try it yet, but then but the SO and the executable will have its own copy of the Queue<int>, do you really think it works fine?

Comment: @lzprgmr: the executable won't have a copy I believe -- you never instantiate the thing in the executable, do you?